# Is 'to tomorrow' correct?

Tags: prepositions, future-time

> "The meeting is postponed to tomorrow"

Is this grammatically correct? If not, how should it be conveyed?

Comment: the use of "to", "till", or "until" all make sense to me

Comment: I don't hear "postponed to" often. It's either "till" or "until", or things like "moved to".

Comment: @MrLister I think your comment is the best 'answer' so far (for including 'moved to')

Answer (score 3):

"To" is correct.  "Till" or "until" are good alternatives.

Comment: Feel free to dispute, I'm not going to search for citations for this question. Sorry.